# setting / retrieving data from singleton

Tags: ios, singleton

Apple rejected our app siting that page loads times between tabs was too long. Before I was simply calling a webview to display content managed through a CMS. Now we have implemented JSON and I am tring to preload the 5 tabs' data using the singleton design pattern. I can't seem to set the singleton value as I see in examples. On to the code:

header.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
    NSString *someProperty;
    ...
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someProperty;


+ (id)sharedManager;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* tab3data;

@end
```

Implementation.m

```
//Create a seperate thread to download JSON thread
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) //1

//Set JSON URL
#define GWDiOSURL [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://m.web.org/cms_mapper.php"]

#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize someProperty;


- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        someProperty = @"Default Property Value";
    }
    return self;
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"First", @"First");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first"];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    FirstViewController *sharedManager = [FirstViewController sharedManager];

    NSLog(@"Toll%@",sharedManager);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //Get JSON and load into 'data'
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:GWDiOSURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });

}

//Begin JSON Data Parsing and loading
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;

    //Parse JSON
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData

                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    // Load JSON into a dictionary
    NSDictionary *tabData = [json objectForKey:@"mapper"];

    // Get Tab3 data from dictionary
    NSDictionary *tab3 = [tabData objectForKey:@"#tab3_content"];

    // Load Tab3 data into a string from dictionary
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tab3];

    // Verify content via counsel
    //NSLog(@"Second Data:%@",html);

    // Load content into webView
    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

[FirstViewController sharedManager].someProperty = @"asdf";

}


+ (id)sharedManager {
    static FirstViewController *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;

}
```

I need to set the value of html to the singleton. The follow line

```
[FirstViewController sharedManager].someProperty = @"asdf";
```

produces this error

```
Propery 'someProperty' not found on object of type 'id'.
```

I have been trying to get this whole process to work for days.. I appreciate the insight.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your class method, sharedManager, returns an id. Try returning FirstViewController* in sharedManager.

+ (FirstViewController *)sharedManager;

Comment: error: Unexpected interface name 'FirstViewController' expected expression

Comment: Sorry I meant that you should change the prototype. Check the edited answer.

Comment: Ok, I change that to +(FirstViewController*)sharedManager { ... but am still getting the Property 'someProperty' not found on object type 'id'...

Comment: try type casting it? I'm not sure why the compiler would think your returned singleton is of class id if you explicitly return a FirstViewController pointer.